# Alternar entre TabNavigator e StackNavigator no React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Eu tenho um TabNavigator (usei com o createBottomTabNavigator), e todas minhas telas estão nele, uso ele como menu de navegação no aplicativo e ele funciona certinho também. Mas dentro de uma dessas telas tenho um botão e esse botão precisa ir para uma outra tela, e essa outra tela precisa ser do tipo stack navigator. Eu não sei como fazer essa alternância entre tab e o stack.

O código abaixo é do index.js e é onde estão todas as rotas.

```
import Login from './paginas/Login';
import NovaConta from './paginas/NovaConta';
import Inicial from './paginas/Inicial';

import Produtos from './paginas/Produtos';
import Pedidos from './paginas/Pedidos';
import Financeiro from './paginas/Financeiro';
import Perfil from './paginas/Perfil';
import Carrinho from './paginas/Carrinho';
import CarrinhoSelecionarPautas from './paginas/CarrinhoSelecionarPautas';
import ProdutoDetalhes from './paginas/ProdutoDetalhes';
import PedidoDetalhes from './paginas/PedidoDetalhes';

import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react- navigation';

const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        CarrinhoSelecionarPautas: CarrinhoSelecionarPautas
    }
);

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Inicial: Inicial,
        Login: Login,
        NovaConta: NovaConta,
        Produtos: Produtos,
        Pedidos: Pedidos,
        Financeiro: Financeiro,
        Perfil: Perfil,
        Carrinho: Carrinho,
        CarrinhoSelecionarPautas: // go to CarrinhoSelecionarPautas, but through stack navigator,
        ProdutoDetalhes: ProdutoDetalhes,
        PedidoDetalhes: PedidoDetalhes
    },
    {
       backBehavior: 'history',
       initialRouteName: 'Inicial'
    }
);

export default {
    StackNavigator,
    TabNavigator
};
```

Dentro da tela Carrinho eu tenho o botão que vai para a tela CarrinhoSelecionarPautas com alguns parâmetros. E é aqui que quero enviar para o stack.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('CarrinhoSelecionarPautas', {
    carrinho: this.state.carrinho,
    quantidade: this.state.quantidade2,
    pautas: this.state.pautas
})
```

Eu tentei algumas coisas, mas sem sucesso, nada funcionou. Eu comecei com react-native a pouco tempo, então com essa parte estou um pouco confuso. Se alguém puder ajudar serei muito grato.

Comment: Welcome to [pt.so], here being the Portuguese version of StackOverflow, questions should be in Portuguese. Would have [edit] your question? Or visite [so].

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver este problema, você pode colocar o seu StackNavigator dentro do TabNavigator.

Aqui tem um exemplo:

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  createBottomTabNavigator,
  createStackNavigator
} from "react-navigation";

import { colors } from "../styles";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5";
import Dashboard from "../pages/Dashboard/";
import Perfil from "../pages/Perfil";
import NovoMeetup from "../pages/NovoMeetup";
import Busca from "../pages/Busca";
import DetalheMeetup from "../pages/DetalheMeetup";

export default createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    NovoMeetup: {
      screen: NovoMeetup
    },
    App: {
      screen: createStackNavigator(
        {
          Dashboard: { screen: Dashboard },
          Perfil: { screen: Perfil },
          DetalheMeetup: { screen: DetalheMeetup }
        },
        {
          defaultNavigationOptions: {
            header: null
          }
        }
      ),
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
        let tabBarVisible = true;
        const routesWithoutTabs = ["Perfil"];

        if (navigation.state.routes.length > 1) {
          navigation.state.routes.map(route => {
            if (routesWithoutTabs.includes(route.routeName)) {
              tabBarVisible = false;
            }
          });
        }
        let tabBarIcon = ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon name="home" size={20} color={tintColor} />
        );

        return {
          tabBarIcon,
          tabBarVisible
        };
      }
    },
    Busca: {
      screen: Busca
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "App",
    tabBarOptions: {
      showIcon: true,
      showLabel: false,
      activeTintColor: colors.white,
      inactiveTintColor: colors.whiteTransparent,
      style: {
        backgroundColor: colors.primary
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Neste TabNavigator, eu tenho 3 botões, um para a tela "NovoMeetup", outro para a tela "App" e outro para a tela "Busca". A tela padrão deste tab é a tela "App".

Dentro da tela "App", eu tenho um 3 telas. A primeira é a "Dashboard". Dentro dela, eu tenho links para uma tela de "Detalhes". A tela de perfil tem uma navegação diferente, ela abre sem mostrar as abas.